# Combine multiple lines between flags in one line in AWK

Tags: awk

Example file:

```
Pattern 1

AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB

Pattern 2
```

I want to print the lines between two patterns in a file in one line.
From a previous question [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or) I found the very nice

```
awk '/Pattern 1/{flag=1; next} /Pattern 2/{flag=0} flag' file
```

With output:

```
AAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBB
```

My desired output:

```
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: What should happen if `Pattern1` exists but `Pattern2` doesn't or vice-versa? What if both were on 1 line the expected order? What if they were both on 1 line in the reverse order? What if you had a blank line in the middle of the text between the 2 delimiters?

Comment: Can there be multiple occurrences of `Pattern 1 ... Pattern 2` in the input and, if so, do you want all of their contents printed or just the first or just the last or something else?

Comment: In my (lucky) case the patterns are always consistent.

Comment: @anubhava How do I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the output record separator to an empty string by using `-v ORS=`:

```sh
awk -v ORS= '/Pattern 1/{flag=1; next} /Pattern 2/{flag=0} flag' file
```

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/z0maSd).

To print a newline at the end, add `END{print "\n"}`:

```sh
 awk -v ORS= '/Pattern 1/{flag=1; next} /Pattern 2/{flag=0} flag; END{print "\n"}' file > newfile
```

See the Ubuntu 18 screenshot:

[image]

Comment: It will omit final trailing line break as well not just in between

Comment: Exactly as OP wanted, with no newlines in the output. "*I want to print the lines between two patterns in a file in one line.*"

Answer (score 9):

Have your `awk` program in this way, written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/Pattern 2/{
  if(found){
    print val
  }
  found=""
  next
}
/Pattern 1/{
  found=1
  next
}
found{
  val=val $0
}
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
/Pattern 2/{               ##Checking if Pattern 2 is found here then do following.
  if(found){               ##Checking if found is set then do following.
    print val              ##Printing val here.
  }
  found=""                 ##Nullifying found here.
  next                     ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
/Pattern 1/{               ##Checking if Pattern 1 is found in current line.
  found=1                  ##Setting found to 1 here.
  next                     ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
found{                     ##Checking condition if found is SET then do following.
  val=val $0               ##Creating val variable here which is keep adding current line values in it.
}
'  Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 9):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '/Pattern 2/ {if (s!="") print s; s=f=""} f {s = s $0} /Pattern 1/ {f=1}' file

AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: In  the case of `Pattern 1 foo Pattern 1 bar Pattern 2` that would print `foobar` while [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66746370/1745001) would print `bar`. idk which is correct, just mentioning the difference as the provided example doesn't cover that case.

Comment: yes that's a very good point, not sure which one OP wants

Answer (score 5):

And also with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS= '!/Pattern/ {sub(/\n/,"");print}' file
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB
```

Comment: I don't think you can assume that `Pattern 1` and `Pattern 2` share a common substring `Pattern`, I think those terms are just [bad] examples the OP used, nor that they don't occur elsewhere in the text, nor that they're always in the order required for printing (e.g. `Pattern 2... Pattern 1`).

Comment: Ok. Now I see how the word `pattern` can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and assuming your "Pattern"s really to take up whole lines and can't occur elsewhere in your input (easy fix if that's wrong):

```
$ awk -v RS='Pattern 2' 'sub(/.*Pattern 1/,""){gsub(/\n/,""); print}' file
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB
```

or with any awk:

```
awk 'f{ if (/Pattern 2/){print buf; f=0} else buf=buf $0 } /Pattern 1/{f=1; buf=""}' file
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB
```