# How to print lines between two patterns with optional end pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have gone through stack over flow and found these questions

[How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or)

[Combine multiple lines between flags in one line in AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66737726/combine-multiple-lines-between-flags-in-one-line-in-awk)

The problem with my question is that there can be another TAG1 without the matching TAG2 like this

file.txt:

```
aa

TAG1
some right text
TAG2

some text2

TAG1
some text3

TAG1
some text4

TAG1
some right text 2
TAG2

some text4

TAG1
some text5
some text6
```

expected output:

```
TAG1
some right text
TAG2

TAG1
some right text 2
TAG2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to reverse the input, get `TAG2` to `TAG1` and then reverse again:

```bash
$ tac ip.txt | sed -n '/TAG2/,/TAG1/p' | tac
TAG1
some right text
TAG2
TAG1
some right text 2
TAG2
```

Another way is to reset and start collecting lines once the first one is found and print only when the second one is found:

```bash
$ awk '/TAG1/{f=1; buf=$0; next}
       f{buf=buf ORS $0}
       /TAG2/{if(f) print buf; f=0}' ip.txt
TAG1
some right text
TAG2
TAG1
some right text 2
TAG2
```

Comment: Since files can be large, I would say your second solution is better. Thank you for the quick answer. It works!! Can you also  please help me to understand your solution

What is buf, ORS ? I believe f is a flag here

Comment: Don't assume, measure ;) `buf` is a variable (to denote a buffer that saves the lines of interest). `ORS` is output record separator (default is newline character), `$0` won't have line endings, so you need to add them manually. `f` is also a variable, used here as a state machine flag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with GNU sed. Collect the data into pattern space and only print when matching TAG1/TAG2 found:

```
sed -nE ':a; /TAG1$/ s/.*(TAG1)/\1/; N; /TAG2$/ { /^TAG1/ { G; p; }; z; }; ba'
```

Or as a stand-alone script with explanation:

*parse.sed*

```
:a                            # main-loop
/TAG1$/ s/.*(TAG1)/\1/        # Ensure only one TAG1 
N                             # Read next line
/TAG2$/ {                     # When TAG2 encountered
  /^TAG1/ { G; p; }           # Which started with a TAG1, print
  z                           # Clear out pattern space
}
ba                            # Repeat main-loop
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -nEf parse.sed infile
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too! although I couldn't understand a bit :)

Comment: @satya: added some explanation